# Combining two UPDATE statement with one SET statement with WHERE clause and one SET without

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to combine this query into one UPDATE statement?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET Column1 = Column2

UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET Column3 = 1
WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: That depends - is the `Column1` check in the second statement meant to be the final state of `Column1` after the first statement has executed or is it meant to be the state of the column from before that time?

Comment: T-SQL, SQL-server 2012 and before that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE [DBO].[MyTable]
SET Column1 = Column2,
    Column3 = (
  CASE
    WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE Column3
  END)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET Column1 = Column2
    ,Column3 = 
    case 
         when Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         else Column3 
     end
```

Comment: This causes `Column3` to be set to `NULL` when `Column1` is null.

Comment: in cases when the Column1 is not null, you will set the Column3 to null

Comment: @Lesya Thanks for the good eyes - in a hurry to answer.  Answer updated.